# Nested child elements not displaying in JSON column formatting in Microsoft List in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am trying to create a `Status` column which displays the progress of a multi stage approval flow.

To recreate the setup in your own environment, create the following columns in a Microsoft List:

- `Status` (type: Single Line of Text)
- `Stage1Person` (type: Person)
- `Stage2Person` (type: Person)
- `Stage3Person` (type: Person)

And then paste either of the JSON column formatting examples below to the `Status` column.

The logic of the JSON column formatting is:

- If `Stage1Person` has a value, apply a background color to the first stage indicator
- If `Stage2Person` has a value, apply a background color to the second stage indicator
- If `Stage3Person` has a value, apply a background color to the third stage indicator

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/9sth607q/) demonstrates how it should look (notice the arrows):

[image]

I am now converting the HTML and CSS into the JSON required for column formatting.

All the conditional logic and colors are working, however it is not outputting the nested child elements.

The nested child elements (spans) are the 'arrows' at the end of each stage.

The column formatting therefore looks like this (notice the arrows are not showing):

[image]

The associated HTML in browser developer tools console looks like this:

(you can see that the nested spans are not being output at all)

[image]

At first, I was wondering if nested `children` were allowed in JSON column formatting.

But I have seen other examples where people are using it ([example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/284751)), so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Below is the JSON column formatting I am using.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style":
    {
        "font-size": "16px"
    },
    "children":
    [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Stage 01",
            "style":
            {
                "float": "left",
                "padding": "10px 30px 10px 40px",
                "position": "relative",
                "font-family": "Arial",
                "background-color": "=if([$Stage1Person] == '', '#eee', '#aeffae')"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "style":
                    {
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "top": "0",
                        "right": "-19px",
                        "width": "0",
                        "height": "0",
                        "border-top": "21px solid transparent",
                        "border-bottom": "20px solid transparent",
                        "z-index": "2",
                        "background-color": "=if([$Stage1Person] == '', '#eee', '#aeffae')"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Stage 02",
            "style":
            {
                "float": "left",
                "padding": "10px 30px 10px 40px",
                "position": "relative",
                "font-family": "Arial",
                "background-color": "=if([$Stage2Person] == '', '#ffdcae', '#aeffae')"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "style":
                    {
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "top": "0",
                        "right": "-19px",
                        "width": "0",
                        "height": "0",
                        "border-top": "21px solid transparent",
                        "border-bottom": "20px solid transparent",
                        "z-index": "2",
                        "background-color": "=if([$Stage2Person] == '', '#ffdcae', '#aeffae')"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Stage 03",
            "style":
            {
                "float": "left",
                "padding": "10px 30px 10px 40px",
                "position": "relative",
                "font-family": "Arial",
                "background-color": "=if([$Stage3Person] == '', '#ffaeae', '#aeffae')"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "style":
                    {
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "top": "0",
                        "right": "-19px",
                        "width": "0",
                        "height": "0",
                        "border-top": "21px solid transparent",
                        "border-bottom": "20px solid transparent",
                        "z-index": "2",
                        "background-color": "=if([$Stage3Person] == '', '#ffaeae', '#aeffae')"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Simplified JSON**

Here is a more simplified version which also demonstrates how the nested CHILD elements are not being output as HTML:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style":
    {
        "font-size": "16px"
    },
    "children":
    [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Stage 01",
            "style":
            {
                "float": "left",
                "padding": "10px 30px 10px 40px",
                "position": "relative",
                "font-family": "Arial",
                "background-color": "=if([$Stage1Person] == '', '#eee', '#aeffae')"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "txtContent": "Stage 01 - CHILD"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Stage 02",
            "style":
            {
                "float": "left",
                "padding": "10px 30px 10px 40px",
                "position": "relative",
                "font-family": "Arial",
                "background-color": "=if([$Stage2Person] == '', '#ffdcae', '#aeffae')"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "txtContent": "Stage 02 - CHILD"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "Stage 03",
            "style":
            {
                "float": "left",
                "padding": "10px 30px 10px 40px",
                "position": "relative",
                "font-family": "Arial",
                "background-color": "=if([$Stage3Person] == '', '#ffaeae', '#aeffae')"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "txtContent": "Stage 03 - CHILD"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Update:**

I just came across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#children):

> children
> An optional property that specifies child elements of the element specified by elmType. The value is specified as an array of elm objects. **There can be an arbitrary level of nesting. If an element has the txtContent property, the child properties are ignored.**

So, nested children ARE supported, but if a top level element has the `txtContent` property, then the child elements are not rendered.

So this works because there is no `textContent` property in the top element:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-size": "16px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "Stage 01 - CHILD"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "Stage 02 - CHILD"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "Stage 03 - CHILD"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I just need to figure out how to get the desired behaviour, without having `txtContent` specified in the parent elements.

Comment: These are not JSON  (JSON is a string) but JavaScript objects perhaps.  https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Show what you have tried and the challenge it presents you so we can perhaps better assist you in fixing it.

Comment: There are two examples of the JSON column formatting I have tried, as well as a link to a JSFiddle showing the desired behavior using HTML and CSS, in the original question. It also includes screenshots of desired behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: I have added sample JSON and my test results below. let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most elegant way to do it.

But it seems to get the desired behaviour.

I refactored the HTML so that no 'parent' divs contained `txtContent`.

The HTML structure is essentially this:

```html
<div id='stage_container_01'>
  <div class='stage done'>Stage 01</div>
  <div class='arrow done'></div>
</div>
<div id='stage_container_02'>
  <div class='stage current'>Stage 02</div>
  <div class='arrow current'></div>
</div>
<div id='stage_container_03'>
  <div class='stage todo'>Stage 03</div>
  <div class='arrow todo'></div>
</div>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle showing the HTML/CSS solution](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/dvjcgtas)

Then I translated that into JSON column formatting:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style":
    {
        "font-size": "16px"
    },
    "children":
    [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style":
            {
                "position": "relative",
                "z-index": "3"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "Stage 01",
                    "style":
                    {
                        "float": "left",
                        "padding": "10px 30px 10px 40px",
                        "position": "relative",
                        "font-family": "Arial",
                        "background-color": "=if([$Stage1Person] == '', '#eee', '#aeffae')"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style":
                    {
                        "float": "left",
                        "width": "0",
                        "height": "0",
                        "border-top": "21px solid transparent",
                        "border-bottom": "17px solid transparent",
                        "border-left": "19px solid",
                        "border-left-color": "=if([$Stage1Person] == '', '#eee', '#aeffae')"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style":
            {
                "position": "relative",
                "z-index": "2",
                "left": "-19px"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "Stage 02",
                    "style":
                    {
                        "float": "left",
                        "padding": "10px 30px 10px 40px",
                        "position": "relative",
                        "font-family": "Arial",
                        "background-color": "=if([$Stage2Person] == '', '#ffdcae', '#aeffae')"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style":
                    {
                        "float": "left",
                        "width": "0",
                        "height": "0",
                        "border-top": "21px solid transparent",
                        "border-bottom": "17px solid transparent",
                        "border-left": "19px solid",
                        "border-left-color": "=if([$Stage2Person] == '', '#ffdcae', '#aeffae')"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style":
            {
                "position": "relative",
                "z-index": "1",
                "left": "-38px"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "Stage 03",
                    "style":
                    {
                        "float": "left",
                        "padding": "10px 30px 10px 40px",
                        "position": "relative",
                        "font-family": "Arial",
                        "background-color": "=if([$Stage3Person] == '', '#ffaeae', '#aeffae')"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style":
                    {
                        "float": "left",
                        "width": "0",
                        "height": "0",
                        "border-top": "21px solid transparent",
                        "border-bottom": "17px solid transparent",
                        "border-left": "19px solid",
                        "border-left-color": "=if([$Stage3Person] == '', '#ffaeae', '#aeffae')"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This outputs the following in a list:

[image]

I think it looks a bit weird without a border on the right side of the arrow.

But the arrow itself is the result of a 19px border, so not sure how to put a border on a border :/.

Here's another approach which creates separation between different completed stages.

But it still looks a bit dodgy:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below JSON should help you to get started with:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "height": "70px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "container"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "stage done"
      },
      "style": {
        "float": "left",
        "padding": "28px 35px 10px 40px",
        "position": "relative",
        "font-family": "Arial",
        "background-color": "#aeffae",
        "width": "50px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "txtContent": "Submitted",
          "style": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": "30px",
            "top": "12px"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "attributes": {
            "class": "arrow"
          },
          "style": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": "0",
            "right": "-19px",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "border-top": "21px solid transparent",
            "border-bottom": "17px solid transparent",
            "z-index": "2",
            "border-left": "19px solid #aeffae"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "stage current"
      },
      "style": {
        "float": "left",
        "padding": "28px 35px 10px 40px",
        "position": "relative",
        "font-family": "Arial",
        "background-color": "#ffdcae",
        "width": "50px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "txtContent": "Approved",
          "style": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": "30px",
            "top": "12px"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "attributes": {
            "class": "arrow"
          },
          "style": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": "0",
            "right": "-19px",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "border-top": "21px solid transparent",
            "border-bottom": "17px solid transparent",
            "z-index": "2",
            "border-left": "19px solid #ffdcae"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "stage todo"
      },
      "style": {
        "float": "left",
        "padding": "28px 35px 10px 40px",
        "position": "relative",
        "font-family": "Arial",
        "background-color": "#ffaeae",
        "width": "50px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "txtContent": "Authorised",
          "style": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": "30px",
            "top": "12px"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "attributes": {
            "class": "arrow"
          },
          "style": {
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": "0",
            "right": "-19px",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "border-top": "21px solid transparent",
            "border-bottom": "17px solid transparent",
            "z-index": "2",
            "border-left": "19px solid #ffaeae"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Change the background-color and other styling properties based on your conditions.

**Output**:

[image]